# callback function throws unexpected "nonconformant arguments" error

Tags: octave, uicontrol

I'm using GNU Octave, version 4.4.1. I'm trying to make an interactive plot of a simple oscillator by including two sliders which would allow the initial velocity and oscillator mass to be changed.
The plot itself shows fine, as well as the script with one slider (for velocity). Here's a part of that script with the callback function:

```
function titranje_ia1 (hslider, event)

v0 = get ( hslider, "value" );
m = 1;
k = 1;
t = 0:0.1:30;
x = v0*sin(sqrt(k/m)*t);
axes ('position', [0.1, 0.2, 0.8, 0.75]);
h = plot ( t, x );
axis ([0 30 -11 11]);
set (h, "linewidth", 2);
set (gca, "xlabel", "t (s)", "ylabel", "x (m)", "fontsize", 12);
set (gca, 'XTick', 0:pi:10*pi)
set (gca, 'XTickLabel', {'0','\pi','2\pi','3\pi','4\pi','5\pi','6\pi','7\pi','8\pi','9\pi','10\pi'})
grid on;
l = legend (sprintf('v0 = %f', v0));
set (l, "fontsize", 12)

endfunction
```

However, when I include a second slider

```
function titranje_ia2 (hslider1, hslider2, event)

v0 = get ( hslider1, "value" );
m = get ( hslider2, "value" );
k = 1;
t = 0:0.1:30;
x = v0.*sin(sqrt(k./m).*t);
axes ('position', [0.1, 0.2, 0.8, 0.75]);
h = plot ( t, x );
axis ([0 30 -11 11]);
set (h, "linewidth", 2);
set (gca, "xlabel", "t (s)", "ylabel", "x (m)", "fontsize", 12);
set (gca, 'XTick', 0:pi:10*pi)
set (gca, 'XTickLabel', {'0','\pi','2\pi','3\pi','4\pi','5\pi','6\pi','7\pi','8\pi','9\pi','10\pi'})
grid on;
l = legend (sprintf('v0 = %f', v0));
set (l, "fontsize", 12)

endfunction
```

I receive an error:

> > error: titranje_ia2: product: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 0x0, op2 is 1x301)
> > execution error in graphics callback function

Since I know that 'k' is a scalar and 't' a vector (but I'm not sure what v0 and m would be; I suppose scalars), I included an elementwise operations in function 'x' definition. 't' size is 1x301, so I assume that 'sqrt(k./m)' is 0x0 (as seen by Octave). Shouldn't it be 1x1?
Indeed, when I try

```
size(m)
```

I receive ans = 0 0 (for size(v0) I get ans = 1 1). Could it be that there is a problem with slider definition? I include at the end both slider definitions:

```
%Definiramo ui element: 'klizac' za v0
hslider1 = uicontrol (
"style", "slider",
"units", "normalized",
"position", [0.1, 0.0, 0.8, 0.1],
"min", 1,
"max", 10,
"value", 4,
"callback", @titranje_ia2
);

%Definiramo ui element: 'klizac' za m
hslider2 = uicontrol (
"style", "slider",
"units", "normalized",
"position", [0.1, 0.05, 0.8, 0.1],
"min", 1,
"max", 10,
"value", 1,
"callback", @titranje_ia2
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be misunderstanding a bit how callbacks work. Whenever you interact with a uicontrol object, the associated callback is *always* called automatically with [at least] *two* arguments: the first is always the 'handle' of the corresponding uicontrol object that triggerred he callback, and the second is the type of 'event' that was triggered. Therefore your callback function needs to *always* have a signature of `callbackname( hndl, evt )` at the very least, so that it can handle those two arguments passed to it by default.

You can specify **extra** arguments to passed to the callback if you want, but these will necessarily be interpreted as 3rd, 4th, and so on, inside the callback function (see example below).

If you have a case like yours where you don't really care *where* the event originated from, and you want to affect (or in this case 'read from') two existing uicontrols in a single callback, regardless which one triggerred the event, the simplest thing to do is to make both slider handles to be extra arguments to the callback, and simply ignore the first argument (i.e. the 'active handle') inside your callback. (in fact, you're already ignoring the 'event' argument too!).

Here's an example:

```
%% In file makesliders.m
function makesliders()
  % Label and slider for initial velocity
    IV_label  = uicontrol( 'style', 'text'  , 'units', 'normalized', 'position', [0.10, 0.025, 0.30, 0.075], 'string', 'Initial Velocity' );
    IV_slider = uicontrol( 'style', 'slider', 'units', 'normalized', 'position', [0.45, 0.025, 0.50, 0.075], 'min', 1, 'max', 10 );

  % Label and slider for oscillator mass
    OM_label  = uicontrol( 'style', 'text'  , 'units', 'normalized', 'position', [0.10, 0.125, 0.30, 0.075], 'string', 'Oscillator Mass ' );
    OM_slider = uicontrol( 'style', 'slider', 'units', 'normalized', 'position', [0.45, 0.125, 0.50, 0.075], 'min', 1, 'max', 10 );

  % Set callbacks and initial values to IV and OM sliders, and plot initial graph
    v0_init = 4;   m_init = 1;
    set( IV_slider, 'value', v0_init, 'callback', { @slider_callback, IV_slider, OM_slider } );
    set( OM_slider, 'value', m_init , 'callback', { @slider_callback, IV_slider, OM_slider } );
    plot_oscillation( v0_init, m_init );
endfunction

function slider_callback (active_handle, event, IV_slider, OM_slider )
    v0 = get( IV_slider, 'value' );
    m  = get( OM_slider, 'value' );
    plot_oscillation( v0, m );
endfunction

function plot_oscillation( v0, m )
    k  = 1;
    t  = 0 : 0.1 : 30;
    x = v0 * sin( sqrt( k / m ) * t );

    h = plot( t, x );   set( h  , 'linewidth', 2);
    set( gca, 'position', [0.1, 0.325, 0.85, 0.650], 'xlim', [0, 30], 'ylim', [-11, 11], 'xlabel', 't (s)', 'ylabel', 'x (m)', 'fontsize', 12, 'xtick', [0 : pi : 10 * pi], 'xticklabel', strcat( arrayfun( @num2str, 0:10, 'uniformoutput', false ), '\pi' ), 'xgrid', 'on', 'ygrid', 'on' );
    l = legend( sprintf( 'v0 = %.2f, m = %.2f', v0, m ) );   set( l, 'fontsize', 12 );
endfunction
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Tasos, thanks for the clarification and help. If I understand correctly now, I defined the callback function in a wrong way, regarding its arguments. Octave interpreted hslider2 as a triggering event and not as an argument. Therefore, it couldn't read the slider control values. What I still don't understand is why am I ignoring the handle and event in the callback. Shouldn't handle refer to the source of the callback?

Comment: @user5694985 you mean, why I chose to ignore them in my answer? Simple, doing it this way allowed me to define a single callback that changes things in both handles of interest, without caring which object called it specifically. If I relied on the 'source handle' instead, I'd have to create a separate callback for each uicontrol object, and pass the handle for the non-source handle as an extra parameter (since I need to use that inside the callback too). Doing it this way effectively allows me to have a single, general callback instead of two specific ones that need to detect the source.